# Lockscreen widgets are unresponsive for several seconds

Tags: ios

I often use the Siri suggested apps widget to start an app. After upgrade to iOS 10, I have noticed that I have to press several times on the app icon before it responds. If I wait a couple of seconds before pressing it the first time, it will respond. It feels like all the other widgets has to load their content before I can start the app.

This lag kind of defeats the main purpose of ***quick access*** to an app as I have used it for in the past.

Is this a known issue? Is it possible to do something to fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually an 'issue' that needs 'fixing'.  These widgets, most likely, have to make some kind of internet query to get their data and refresh the interface.  That can take several seconds depending on the speed of your internet connection.  It's best to wait a second or two for the widgets to get their data.

Comment: The specific "issue" I feel is a bug is it displays a set of app icons, then it "recalculates" and might change to a different set of app icons. Before the upgrade to iOS 10 it also changed after some seconds, but it was possible to click on it before it changed, but now it does not respond.